# Showing specific data without filtering out query data

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I need to build a form where one field (Unplanned Amount) will only populate with data if another field (status) equals a certain value ("not in workflow").  If the status equals anything else, Unplanned amount field would be blank.

The data is coming from three different tables:

Table 1) AccountNum
Table 2) DocNum, DocAmount, DocStatus
Table 3) CommitAmount

The value in CommitAmount will always equal DocAmount, but the value of DocAmount doesn't have to equal the value of the CommitAmount if it's "unplanned."

I tried putting the data into a query and using the following code on my form to no avail:

```
 If Me.DocStatus = "Not in workflow" Then
 Me.DocAmount = Null
 Else
 Me.DocAmount = [forms]![form2]![DocAmount]
 End If
```

Does anyone know how to go about making a query-based form or report that allows what I've described above to take place? Or maybe this should not be done via a query?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Put the IF statement into to data source for me.docamount 
OR use a case statement in the query itself
select case docstatus when 'Not in workflow' then null else docamount end